# How to implement Progressbar for Android WebView in Ajax Calls

Tags: ajax, android-webview, loading, android-progressbar

I implemented Progress bar loader for android web view,

But the progress bar not dismissed after the response came in AJAX calls.
Whenever I clicked ajax calls based link in that site,progress bar appearing but not dismissed ,after getting the response also.

How can I overcome this.